# Rails - in what order does dependent => destroy follow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

Given this example:

```
class Server < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients,:dependent => :destroy 
  after_destroy: delete_server_directory
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :server

  before_destroy :copy_some_important_stuff_from_the_server_directory_before_its_too_late
end
```

Will this be the order of destruction when I call `server.destroy`?

1. `Server#clients`, along with `Client`'s `before/after_destroy` callbacks
2. `Server` will be destroyed
3. followed by the `Server`'s `after_destroy` callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can very easily test. I took your code, and implemented the callbacks with a simple call to `puts`. Then launched `script/console` and had ActiveRecord log to the console:

```
>> ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
=> #<Logger:0x0000000308d2f0 ...>
```

Set up some basic environment:

```
>> a = Client.create :name => 'Client 1'
  Client Create (0.4ms)   INSERT INTO "clients" ("name", "server_id") VALUES('Client 1', NULL)
=> #<Client id: 1, name: "Client 1", server_id: nil>
>> b = Client.create :name => 'Client 2'
  Client Create (0.5ms)   INSERT INTO "clients" ("name", "server_id") VALUES('Client 2', NULL)
=> #<Client id: 2, name: "Client 2", server_id: nil>
>> server = Server.create :name => 'The Server'
  Server Create (0.3ms)   INSERT INTO "servers" ("name") VALUES('The Server')
=> #<Server id: 1, name: "The Server">
>> server.clients = [a, b]
  Client Load (0.4ms)   SELECT * FROM "clients" WHERE ("clients".server_id = 1) 
  Client Update (0.4ms)   UPDATE "clients" SET "server_id" = 1 WHERE "id" = 1
  Client Update (0.2ms)   UPDATE "clients" SET "server_id" = 1 WHERE "id" = 2
=> [#<Client id: 1, name: "Client 1", server_id: 1>, #<Client id: 2, name: "Client 2", server_id: 1>]
```

And here's the gist of it:

```
>> server.destroy
>>> copy_some_important_stuff_from_the_server_directory_before_its_too_late called!
  Client Destroy (0.5ms)   DELETE FROM "clients" WHERE "id" = 1
>>> copy_some_important_stuff_from_the_server_directory_before_its_too_late called!
  Client Destroy (0.2ms)   DELETE FROM "clients" WHERE "id" = 2
  Server Destroy (0.2ms)   DELETE FROM "servers" WHERE "id" = 1
>>> delete_server_directory called!
=> #<Server id: 1, name: "The Server">
```

So it looks like you were dead on target. :)

P.S.

- There's a small syntax error in the server model's `after_destroy`.
- I assume with step 1 you really meant `before_destroy`, as seen in your example.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, I came here wanting to understand how rails works and this doesn't really help me understand how to control the order of destroy operations.